# Python inotify (pyinotify) over FTP

Tags: python, ftp, pyinotify

I need to listen file events for my remote server over `FTP`. I've found `pyinotify` to detect file changes in `Python`. It detects well on local file system and I think it is very good.

But when I gave a `FTP` addres to make it watch, it does not see the path as appropriate and gives me ;

```
pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch ftp://myuser@myserver/home/myUser WD=-1, Errno=No such file or directory (ENOENT)
```

I also tried with url `ftp://myuser@myserver`, but the result was same.

So, What am I missing with `pyinotify`, is it available to listen file changes over FTP with pyinotify?

If it is not available, could you suggest another library to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you try this from the command line: `ls  'ftp://myuser@myserver/home/myUser'`?

Comment: `ls` works for `file://` access type. There are many accessing with different access type or protocol. `file`, `ftp`, `http`, `https`, `ssh`, etc. It does not matter which one you use. One of them is a web browser as an example. I need a solution such that. So the answer is not related with what `ls` does.

Comment: it IS related.  `ls` does not work because the path you give is not a file type.  `inotify` only works on files.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to run pynotify over FTP, NFS, or anything other than local file systems.

You'll need to poll the remote FTP server using an FTP library to detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe it is because `ftp://...` **isn't a folder**. It is just a weblink. If you want to run pynotify over FTP, I think you have to upload file on the server, and run it there.

---

Or you can use `ftplib` for that. You just always list directory and get changes.

Answer (score 0):

pyinotify is used only for directories and files.To monitor ftp, you can't make use of pyinotify.